# Error on connecting to MongoDB after updating Intellij: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.<init>(I)V

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

Yesterday after updating Intellij version from 2019 to 2020 I had an issue with spring boot in connecting to mongoDB with JPA, it was funny that after updating IDEA to new version my project could not run.
Even I checked it on another PC and the problem repeated and with the same solution it was resolved.
Finally I could solve it but I don not know the reason of happening this issue, I will appreciate any clues or help for the cause of this error.

this is the error that was thrown in console:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'siteSandBox': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'siteService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'siteService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoSiteRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoSiteRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDbFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.<init>(I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1268) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at ir.anarestan.ipc.boot.Boot.main(Boot.java:15) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'siteService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoSiteRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoSiteRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDbFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.<init>(I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1268) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoSiteRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDbFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.<init>(I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1280) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDbFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.<init>(I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1071) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDbFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.<init>(I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1071) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.<init>(I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1071) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.<init>(I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.<init>(I)V
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.clientMetadataDocumentTooLarge(ClientMetadataHelper.java:204) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.createClientMetadataDocument(ClientMetadataHelper.java:168) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.createClientMetadataDocument(ClientMetadataHelper.java:149) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionFactory.<init>(InternalStreamConnectionFactory.java:41) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterableServerFactory.create(DefaultClusterableServerFactory.java:68) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createServer(BaseCluster.java:360) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SingleServerCluster.<init>(SingleServerCluster.java:54) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:744) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:728) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:702) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:310) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:306) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:284) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties.createNetworkMongoClient(MongoProperties.java:257) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties.createMongoClient(MongoProperties.java:208) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:73) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e221a84c.CGLIB$mongo$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e221a84c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e210c9d2.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e221a84c.mongo(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    ... 83 common frames omitted
```

And the solution was adding an library in Gradle as below and it was resolved:

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.11.0'
}
```

Comment: Check the libraries imported, maybe it imports dependencies from Javax and not spring-data-MongoDB